# Kerberos: What is the structure for preauthentication with certificate (RFC 4556)

Tags: authentication, kerberos

I'm struggling to understand what the structure of a preauthentication request in kerberos should look like. After reading RFC 4556 and the referenced RFCs I'm still confused because of all the different cases.

My usecase is as follows: I want to authenticate on a windows domain with a certificate I retrieved from the CA belonging to the domain. The certificate contains the crl-URL and it's signature-algorithm is sha256RSA. The contained public key is a RSA2048 key.
As far as I understand I should send this certificate and sign it. I'm also aware that I have to send a nonce to avoid replay attacks.

I'm  unclear what has to be signed, i.e. what has to be in this part of the request.

```
PA-PK-AS-REQ ::= SEQUENCE {
          signedAuthPack          [0] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING,
                   -- Contains a CMS type ContentInfo encoded
                   -- according to [RFC3852].
```

RFC 3852 states:

```
SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
        version CMSVersion,
        digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
        encapContentInfo EncapsulatedContentInfo,
        certificates [0] IMPLICIT CertificateSet OPTIONAL,
        crls [1] IMPLICIT RevocationInfoChoices OPTIONAL,
        signerInfos SignerInfos }
```

Although there's a lot of explanation to all these points, I'm afraid I'm a dummie as I just don't get it. Especially what belongs into version and encapContentInfo (I think the signature should go into the econtent-Field of the EncapsulatedContentInfo, but I'm not sure).

As the spec is a little confusing I just don't get what else has to be in this request and what not.

Can anybody shed a little light on this and clarify how the structure of the complete request should look like?

**EDIT**

OK, after some research I am even more confused. RFC 4556 states that the structure of PkAuthenticator in the AuthPack should look like this:

```
PKAuthenticator ::= SEQUENCE {
    cusec                   [0] INTEGER -- (0..999999) --,
    ctime                   [1] KerberosTime,
    nonce                   [2] INTEGER (0..4294967295),
    paChecksum              [3] OCTET STRING OPTIONAL,
    ...
}
```

Sniffing the smartcard-authentication-traffic with wireshark I got this PKAuthenticator-structure in a microsoft-environment:

```
SEQUENCE(1 elem)
    [0](1 elem)
        SEQUENCE(5 elem)
            [0](1 elem)
                SEQUENCE(2 elem)
                    [0](1 elem)
                        INTEGER2
                    [1](1 elem)
                        SEQUENCE(2 elem)
                            GeneralString
                            GeneralString
            [1](1 elem)
                GeneralString
            [2](1 elem)
                INTEGER 563793
            [3](1 elem)
                GeneralizedTime 2016-12-01 13:53:08 UTC
            [4](1 elem)
                INTEGER 1051204026
```

Is this the usual behaviour of microsoft doing their own thing regardless of what the spec says or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm addressing the question you added with your edit.

[As documented by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc238470.aspx), some Windows versions (*"<2> Section 2.2: [RFC4556] message syntax is not supported in Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003."*) are based on an earlier draft of RFC 4556 that defined the following structure for PKAuthenticator ([draft version 11](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cat-kerberos-pk-init-11) was the last to use this syntax for `PKAuthenticator`):

```
--
-- PK-AUTHENTICATOR - Different from [RFC4556]
-- Appendix A, PKAuthenticator.
--
PKAuthenticator::= SEQUENCE {
     kdc-name   [0] PRINCIPAL-NAME,
     kdc-realm  [1] REALM,
 -- name and realm of the KDC issuing the ticket
     cusec      [2] INTEGER,
     ctime      [3] KerberosTime,
     nonce      [4] INTEGER
 }
```

With the final RFC (draft [version 22](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cat-kerberos-pk-init-22) actually) the identifier for PA-PK-AS-REP also changed from 15 to 17 to distinguish between the two format specifications (Microsoft mentions that too: *"An earlier draft of [RFC4556] supported a different pre-authentication data identifier: PA-PK-AS-REP_OLD 15"*).